# Wifi on Debian on Dell E7270

Tags: debian, wifi, firmware, iwlwifi

Network manager doesn't see wifi card. Card keep being disabled after restart. Something overwrites `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have problem using wifi it's probably lack of firmware or conflicts. **`connman` conflicts with network manager**. `wicd` also can canflict but I can't confirm. You should remove both of them and stick with `network-manager`.

You should also copy wifi firmware file into `/lib/firmware`. I don't remember the name and version but if you run `dmesg | grep ilwifi`.

I found old version of firmware [here](https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/blob/master/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode) and the newer [here](https://github.com/NetBit73/NeteXt73_pakiety/blob/master/iwlwifi/iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode)  . Keep in mind I don't remember exact names and version at this moment and it would be better to find more certified source of firmware.

The same is if you want to enable bluetooth. Apart of installing `bluez` package i recommend `dmesg | grep blue`, find firmware and put it `/lib/firmware/intel`

And I recommend installing and/or reconfigure `resolvconf`.

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of the wifi firmware are available direct from Intel.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html

Comment: I found a better source, from here:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/commit/?id=7020dc6c88c950a7ac798dc3ba91b22a3a3976bd

I downloaded the tarball, extracted it, and used ``Rsync -a'' to copy the entire contents into /lib/firmware. After this, Wifi and Bluetooth started working. I hope this is of assistance to someone.